# I have several images that keep reverting to an old state when creating new branches from master

Tags: git

I have a repository for a WordPress theme. One folder in it contains favicons and app icons. A few months ago, we updated these to new images.

Now somewhere approaching half of the time that I create a new feature branch from master, some of the old image files come up replacing the new ones in the new branch.

I've replaced them again directly in the master branch and deleted all other branches and still, they keep coming back. I'm at a loss here. The only thing I can think of now is to create a new repository from the current theme's files, but I'd really prefer not to lose the history of the project.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: I don't have very much experience with GIT, but my understanding is that arbitrary binary files are difficult to for GIT. Back when I messed with git and svn, the idea was that images etc probably ought to be kept separate and if not, they might need some manual massaging. This was years ago though. Look into "Git diff image binary issues"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out not to be a GIT issue.

I am starting to use a Gulp build process and implemented a /raw/ images folder for images to be processed by Gulp and then written to the main images folder.

Then I promptly forgot the folder existed and started putting images into the regular image folder, where gulp dutifully overwrote them as it was asked to do.